how to import functions inside /static/ dir Django
When i make script for my django project i made a few functions but when i started optimising it and divide for few files i encounter a problem with the importing of function
cart_methods.js
export function cartFunction() {
    console.log("work");
}

home_script.js
import { cartFunction } from './cart_methods.js';
cartFunction();

with this part of code
my .js not work at all
not even small part of code not working. it stop everything
every files is in same folder
static> 
       shop>
             assets>
                     js>
                         cart_methods.js
                         home_script.js
    

 


Please show us your html script tag.

Show us your html code.

@Hujaakbar , i have not problem with importing to html
i need import js function to oter js files
also, script tag   <script src="{% static 'shop/assets/js/home_script.js' %}"></script>

As stated on my answer, add type='module' To your script tag and try again. it is necessary to important from other js files.

Make sure you are adding type='module' to your html script tag and using correct path.
Try out below code:
  <script type="module" src="{% static 'shop/assets/js/home_script.js' %}"></script>

